# One view fo multiple urls to handle multiple languages in django

Tags: django, django-views

I would like to use the same views for different supported languages.
For exemple I have the default language and the english.

In my main urls:

```
url(r'^posts/', include('posts.urls')),     #for default language
url(r'^en/posts/', include('posts.urls')),  #for english
```

The urls file of my posts app is like this:

```
url(r'^newpost/$', views.PostFormView.as_view(), name='add'),
url(r'^favorite/$', views.favorite, name='favorite'),
```

so, for example, both www.mysite.com/posts/add and www.mysite.com/en/posts/add send to the same view PostFormView and according to the url if it contains "/en/" or not I send the content in the right language.

However, the issue is with the redirect or revers sends always to the default language. For example 'posts:add' sends always to "www.mysite.com/posts/add" because I have `url(r'^posts/', include('posts.urls'))` before `url(r'^en/posts/', include('posts.urls'))`

are there any ways to use the same view for two different urls. Or, how can I handle multiple languages website? Do we have to duplicate all the apps for all the supported languages?

Comment: Instead of using different URLs for different languages, have you looked into Django's [internationalization and localization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/) capabilities?

Comment: @ubadub +1,Django originally supported this.

Comment: Doc of i18n urls section is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/translation/#module-django.conf.urls.i18n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a long subject and it's not easy to cover everything but i'll try to cover as much as i can:

**1 - Use django Internationalization and localization:**

Django has a built-in function for multi language websites:

[Internationalization and localization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/)

**2 - Use a single URL with different GET request:**

You can add a GET request in your urls like : `site.com/posts?lang=en`. And try this in your views:

```
language = request.GET.get('lang')
```

and then pass the right template for this language.

example:

```
LANG_LIST = ['en', 'fa', 'fr']
if language.lower() in LANG_LIST:
     template = '{}/posts/post.html'.format(language.lower())
else:
     template = 'en/posts/post.html'
```

or you can use a single template with different language texts and just pass the language to the template and decide there.

**Note:** You should add users language to their session so you can retrieve the language even without a GET request.

Here is the docs for sessions:

[How to use sessions | Django documentation | Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/sessions/)

Also you can add language to your users profile and retrieve the language from there. I recommend using both profile language and user sessions.

**3 - Different urls (Your way):**

I'm not a fan of this way of handling multi language websites really, but if you really need to do it this way then here you go:

- You need different names for your urls lile `posts_en`, `posts_fr` and etc so you can redirect to the right page url.
- You should get the page url in your view and check for language your using. You can do something like this: `request.path.split('/')`.
- Then you should check the language and decide which template to render just like option #2

There can be so many problems with this way of handling multiple languages so i don't think you should go with this one over the other two options.

Comment: I think I'll adept the second method. However, I have another question, how can I redirect or reverse to a view in this case and adding the '?lang=en' to the url ? ex: redirect(posts:add) to get www.mysite.com/posts/newpost/?lang=en

Comment: @A2maridz Well, that were sessions help. You just need to check the sessions to see if there is a language there and if there is, then you have the language you're looking for and if not, just use the default one. Basically every time a user changed the default language, just add the selected language to session so you won't need the 'lang' GET request in future requests.